# How to bind mount static html to nginx

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to bind mount by HTML directory to nginx but whenever I visit the nginx directory to see if it is mounted properly, there I see it is empty.

I am using the following command:

```
docker container run --network nginx -d -p 80:80 --name server -v /html2:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro nginx
```

Am I using the right command? If yes, then what can be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean as "I see it is empty."? This command is correct. In your local directory /html2 you should place your html static files.

Comment: I have placed some html files but i am not able to see them in the nginx directory.

Comment: does your container start without any error? how do you "see them in the nginx directory"? please provide a command